# PowerShell sort array

Tags: powershell

My array is spits out this.

```
a10
a11
a12
a6
a7
a8
a9
```

Any short/simple code to fix it to:

```
a6
a7
a8
a9
a10
a11
a12
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can sort by expression, take everything after the first letter and cast it to integer:

```
$array | sort { [int]$_.substring(1)}
```

You can also make the solution more generic by removing any non-digit characters:

```
$array | sort { [int]($_ -replace '\D')}
```

Comment: Your second line "$array | sort { [int]($_ -replace '\D')}" was able to fix my array filled with "2012-03-02_log-X.txt". Thank you!

Comment: FYI: If you just have an array of string (and smart-numbering is an issue), all you need is `$array | sort`

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way in this case would be to zero-pad all numbers and use that for sorting:

```
$a | sort {
  [Regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', 
  {
    $args[0].Value.PadLeft(10, '0')
  })
}
```

Comment: @Joey $a | sort { $_ -replace '\d+' , $_.padleft(10,'0') } is good the same? or there is something wrong in this way?

Comment: There is. `$_` refers to the complete item, not the match in your case. Therefore the result isn't `a0000000001` but `a00000000a1`. It probably ceases to work with multiple numbers in a string, although I'm too tired now to try. The solution above should yield a »natural« sort with almost any list of strings that contain numbers.

Answer (score 2):

These are hex values, right? ;-)

```
$array | sort {[convert]::toint32("$_",16)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the sort method.

```
$myArray = $myArray | Sort-Object;
```

Some other answers may be more efficient regarding the particular array shown in the question, but in general this will do.

Credit: [Add, Modify, Verify, and Sort Your PowerShell Array - Dr. Scripto](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/add-modify-verify-and-sort-your-powershell-array/)