# powershell advance sorting file names

Tags: powershell, sorting

We have files:

```
CP1-GC1.dem
CP1-GC2.dem
CP1-GC3.dem 

CP5-GC1.dem
CP5-GC4.dem 
CP5-GC3.dem
```

How to get files with largest "GC" number?

Comment: May we see your code?

Comment: looks like i find solution and its realy much easy than 50 lines of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A much more PowerShell like solution:

```
gci *.dem|Sort {$_.Basename.split('-')[1,0]}|Select -Last 1
```

or verbose:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dem | 
  Sort-Object {$_.Basename.split('-')[1,0]} |
    Select-Object -Last 1
```

Result:

```
PS A:\>  gci *.dem|Sort {$_.Basename.split('-')[1,0]}|Select -last 1

    Directory: A:\

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        08/9/2017     23:37              8 CP5-GC4.dem
```

In case the numbers may have different length there is a solution to leftpad the numbers with zeroes [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9518971/6811411)
A bit more complicated ;-) but still a one liner.

```
gci *.dem|sort {[Regex]::Replace($($_.Basename.split('-')[1,0]), '\d+',{$args[0].Value.PadLeft(10, '0') }) }|Select -Last 1
```

Comment: you are amazing, thank you so much! http://imgur.com/a/fAEw0

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading the file names into an array and looping through them I would do something like this:

```
$files = "CP1-GC1.dem
CP1-GC2.dem
CP1-GC3.dem 
CP5-GC1.dem
CP5-GC4.dem 
CP5-GC3.dem" -split "\r\n"

$hn = 0
$hfn = ""

foreach($e in $files)
{
    if($e.SubString(6,1) -gt $hn)
    {
        $hn = $e.SubString(6,1)
        $hfn = $e
    }
}

Write-Host $hn
Write-Host $hfn
```

That will write out the highest number and the name of the file by using SubString() to look a specific character in the string. It then compares it to the highest number so far `$hn` and adjusts the highest file name `$hfn` variable each time a higher number is found.

You would be able to adjust the above code to meet your needs.

Comment: The if with the string first will make it a string comparison, either cast to an int or reverse the order to have it compare numbers as the numbers have different length (see the picture in the comment to my answer)